# Watcher on an object is better or on its attributes?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Am creating a dynamic filter on tables just like phpMyAdmin.

[image]

Here I have created an array and used ng-repeat to have filter on multiple columns.
Initially array is empty and am pushing an object on clicking on plus button.

Now Based on user's column preference, I want to show appropriate input field like if user selects 'created_by', input field should be converted to datetime type. For this I am using a different directive where input field would be converted according to column and filter.

Thats why I want to watch column and filter of each row, which is attribute of object of that array.

```
var filterArr = [];

var filterObj = {
                selectField: self.dictionary,
                filterField: [],
                column:{},
                filter:{},
                inputField: null,
            }

//On Plus button click
filterArr.push(angular.copy(filterObj));
```

So each row has object structure of filterObj and out of which I want to watch column and filter.

Watcher on object of particular element is appropriate or I should use two seperate watcher on column and filter attribute?

Comment: What's is the purpose? Do you have an array with these objects? Please, explain more what you're trying to do.

Comment: Generally you should prefer simple watchers, as they are less expensive. But in this case there is not much difference. It comes down to this: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/rootScope.js#L798 In your case (simple object) I think it will have similar performance to two simple watchers. But maybe you can avoid adding watchers, what is your case exactly?

Comment: If those values are going to change by input fields, then I'd prefer to use `ng-change`

Comment: This feels like an XY Question, and that seems proven by the answer which was presented.  It's not really possible to evaluate which approach would be better without knowing the context of how these approaches are used, and trying to identify how this *might be* used has led to an answer suggesting a different approach entirely.  Perhaps providing more context might narrow the focus of the question some.